# Aws Glue Batch processing using spark engine

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, batch-processing

This is my scenario.

I have a source database which is an aurora database with Postgresql engine. I have a table named `payments`. This table consists of millions of records, so at the end of every day I need to read the data and check for any payments that are past due date, if any payments are past due date, I need to mark the payment as "Overdue".

How can I achieve this in an optimized way using the AWS glue spark job? What are the AWS components that can be leveraged to achieve this requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


# SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "absolutepath/postgresql-42.7.3.jar") \
    .appName("PostgresApp").getOrCreate()



# PostgreSQL connection details
pg_host = "localhost"
pg_port = 5432
pg_database = "test"
pg_user = "test"
pg_password = "test"

# JDBC connection string
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:postgresql://{pg_host}:{pg_port}/{pg_database}?currentSchema=product"



df.show()  # Display the loaded DataFrame


update_query = """
    UPDATE product
    SET product = 'product2'
    WHERE productid= '1'
"""

print("SQL Query:", update_query)
spark.sql(update_query)

# Close connections to avoid resource leaks
spark.stop()
```

Comment: I am new to both spark and batch processing and I see there is no effective way of doing an upsert to the source table from spark script or is there any? Initial assumption design is that we load data from payments identify the payments that are past due dateand mark it as overdue and load theat data into s3. Now from s3, how can I update that data back to the source?

Comment: I can help with an AWS Glue job that connects to postgressql and can update the recods directly into the Payments table. Would you be able use direct update query. Say `UPDATE payments
SET status = 'Overdue'
WHERE due_date < CURRENT_DATE;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) to extract the data from your [Aurora PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraPostgreSQL.html) `payments` table.
The [awsglue python package](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/tree/master/awsglue) should help: you have [many examples in `aws-samples/aws-glue-samples`](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/GlueCustomConnectors/gluescripts/withoutConnection/spark-script-example.py), and you can also include a [DataDirect JDBC driver into DataFrame](https://gist.github.com/saiteja09/2af441049f253d90e7677fb1f2db50cc).

```bash
Aurora DB (PostgreSQL) ──┐
                         │
                         ├─> AWS Glue (ETL) ──> Process ──> S3 (Temporary Storage)
                         │
                         └─<──────────────────<──────────<─ AWS Lambda & RDS Data API
```

From there, filter the records with Spark to identify overdue payments and mark them accordingly. Save the processed data in an Amazon S3 bucket temporarily, and use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/lambda) along with the [RDS Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) (web-services interface to your Aurora DB cluster) to update the original `payments` table based on the data in S3.

```py
import sys
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, col, lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# Reading data from Aurora
payments_df = spark.read.format("jdbc", 
                                url="jdbc:postgresql://<your-aurora-endpoint>:5432/yourdatabase", 
                                dbtable="payments",
                                properties={"user": "yourusername", "password": "yourpassword"})

# Identify overdue payments
overdue_payments_df = payments_df.filter(col("due_date") < current_date())

# Mark payments as Overdue
overdue_payments_marked_df = overdue_payments_df.withColumn("status", lit("Overdue"))

# Save processed data to S3
overdue_payments_marked_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://your-bucket-name/overdue_payments/")
```

Use AWS Lambda, triggered either manually or on a schedule (via [Amazon EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cwe-now-eb.html), formerly CloudWatch Events), to read the processed data from S3 and update the Aurora database using the RDS Data API:

```py
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Access the processed data in S3
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
    with fs.open('s3://your-bucket-name/overdue_payments/', mode='rb') as f:
        overdue_payments_df = pd.read_parquet(f)

    # Convert your DataFrame to SQL update statements

    # Execute SQL updates via RDS Data API
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds-data')
    # Example: update a single record
    rds_client.execute_statement(
        resourceArn='arn:aws:rds:region:account-id:cluster:your-cluster-id',
        secretArn='arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:account-id:secret:your-secret-name',
        database='yourdatabase',
        sql='UPDATE payments SET status = "Overdue" WHERE id = ?;',
        parameters=[{'name':'id', 'value':{'longValue': 123}}]
    )
```

---

[Ananth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812320/ananth-tirumanur)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170348/aws-glue-batch-processing-using-spark-engine/78185189#comment137837405_78170348) to directly update records in the PostgreSQL `payments` table using an SQL `UPDATE` statement is a good alternative, especially if you want transactional integrity and to minimize data movement. That would simplify the process by eliminating the need to temporarily store processed data in S3 and then using AWS Lambda for updates.

The AWS Glue Spark job would execute the SQL update statement directly against the Aurora PostgreSQL database from within the Spark script. Spark itself does not natively execute SQL `UPDATE` statements directly on a JDBC data source.
Instead, you can use the JDBC connection to execute raw SQL commands, but this requires managing the connection yourself within the Spark job, which is not typical Spark usage and may require additional error handling and performance considerations.

An alternative and more Spark-native approach would be to leverage AWS Glue's capability to run a job that triggers an AWS Lambda function, which in turn performs the SQL update operation.
That keeps the heavy lifting within AWS services optimized for these tasks. It is fairly similar to the first part of this answer.

For the direct approach, make sure your AWS Glue job has access to a PostgreSQL JDBC driver. That might involve uploading the driver to S3 and referencing it in your job's dependencies.
Then use, for instance, [PySpark's JDBC capabilities](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to establish a connection to the database and execute an SQL update statement, as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/erikerlandson/755848b2baf2ea34c98a1f4292a7567e).

```py
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, col
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# Database connection properties
database_url = "jdbc:postgresql://<your-aurora-endpoint>:5432/yourdatabase"
connection_properties = {
    "user": "yourusername",
    "password": "yourpassword",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

# SQL to update the payments table
update_query = """
    UPDATE payments
    SET status = 'Overdue'
    WHERE due_date < CURRENT_DATE
"""

# Execute the update query using a JDBC connection
def execute_update_query():
    try:
        # Use Spark's JDBC to execute the update command
        df = spark.read.jdbc(url=database_url, table=f"({update_query}) as payments", properties=connection_properties)
        print("Update query executed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error executing update query: {e}")

# Execute the update function
execute_update_query()
```

Make sure your AWS Glue job has the necessary permissions to access the Aurora PostgreSQL database and execute updates. That typically involves configuring the database's security group to allow connections from AWS Glue and providing the appropriate IAM roles.
That would execute the update without explicit transaction management. Depending on your use case, you may need to handle transactions more granularly, especially if executing multiple updates or if rollback functionality is required.

---

> `pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view payments cannot be found.`

You are trying to use Spark SQL's `spark.sql()` method for executing an SQL `UPDATE` statement, which is not supported directly by Spark SQL. Spark SQL is designed primarily for executing SQL queries that return a DataFrame representing the result set of a SELECT statement or operations like `CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, etc., within the Spark SQL context. It does not support direct DML operations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) on external databases like PostgreSQL through the `spark.sql()` method.

To execute an `UPDATE` statement on a PostgreSQL database from a Spark job, you would need to use a JDBC connection directly, bypassing Spark SQL for the `UPDATE` operation. That would involve using the JDBC API to execute your SQL commands, not through Spark SQL but by establishing a direct connection to your PostgreSQL database (using, for instance, [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)).

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import psycopg2  # Make sure psycopg2 is installed

# SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "absolutepath/postgresql-42.7.3.jar") \
    .appName("PostgresApp").getOrCreate()

# PostgreSQL connection details
pg_host = "localhost"
pg_port = 5432
pg_database = "test"
pg_user = "test"
pg_password = "test"

# Establish a direct JDBC connection to PostgreSQL
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=pg_host,
    port=pg_port,
    dbname=pg_database,
    user=pg_user,
    password=pg_password
)
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute the UPDATE command directly via psycopg2, not through Spark SQL
update_query = """
    UPDATE product
    SET product = 'product2'
    WHERE productid = '1'
"""
cursor.execute(update_query)
print(f"{cursor.rowcount} rows updated.")

# Cleanup: close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()

# Do not forget to stop SparkSession at the end of your application
spark.stop()
```

While the `UPDATE` operation is executed outside the Spark SQL context, you can still use Spark for distributed data processing tasks, including reading from and writing to PostgreSQL with `.read.format("jdbc")` and `.write.format("jdbc")`.

Comment: I am getting this error while doing a spark sql update pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `payments` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.; line 2 pos 11;
'UpdateTable [assignment('payments, product2)], ('productid = 1)
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [payments], [], false

Comment: Although, df.read and df.write are working as expected, but if I use spark sql queries getting above error. Added my code to the question, please look

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to import all the data within Glue in order to update the status? If the logic is simple, I would only schedule a job to run a script like this on my database :

```
UPDATE payments SET status = "Overdue" where due_date < current_timestamp
```

You can do this within a glue job or lambda function, I would personally use Glue as I can add new features to the script if needed.

Otherwise, I would use PySpark JDBC to import data more efficient and would skip the s3 step as data can be exported directly back to Aurora.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AWS GLUE, I would suggest you to use Python Shell instead of SPARK, because python shell is much cheaper compared to SPARK.
Your requirement is to update a certain field based on some condition.
Spark doesn't support upsert. It can overwrite or append data.
To perform upsert you need to find the change records and update using maybe psycopg2 execute_values which is the fastest method as far as I know.

```
UPDATE payments SET status = "Overdue" where due_date < now()
```

Here is the code of the python shell job.
Here I have passed all the DB details as job parameters.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions # used to get the job parameters
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=args['db_name'],
                      user=args['db_user'],
                      password=args['db_password'],
                      host=args['db_host'],
                      port=args['db_port'])
cur = conn.cursor()

update_query = ("""UPDATE payments SET status = "Overdue" where due_date < now()""")
cur.execute(update_query)
conn.commit()
```

Provide your DB details and then you can schedule it or call using a lambda function or from another job.
If the update statement is slower try increasing the shared_memory of your DB.